# Force a class to use a constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I have the following class

```
class MyClass
{
    string _val1 = null;
    string _val2 = null;
    string _val3 = null;

    public string Val1{get;set;}
    public string Val2{get;set;}
    public string Val3{get;set;}

    public MyClass(){}
    public MyClass(string val_id1, string val_id2 = null, string val_id3 = null)
    {
        //do some stuff.. set _val1,_val2,_val3
    }
}
```

My intent is to allow it to be instantiated using either of the following methods..

```
//using parameterized constructor
MyClass TestMyClass1 = new MyClass("v1");
MyClass TestMyClass1 = new MyClass("v1","v2");

//using default constructor and setting values
MyClass TestMyClass2 = new MyClass();
TestMyClass.Val1 = "my_test_value1";
TestMyClass.Val2 = "my_test_value2";
TestMyClass.Val3 = "my_test_value3";
```

This seems to work well enough, but I need to force some logic when a value is set explicitly using the default constructor then assigning explicit values to the object.  For instance, I need to using the logic in the parametrized constructor even when someone says `TestMyClass.Val1 = "my_test_value1"`.

So, if `Val1` is being explicitly set.. then the `//do some stuff.. set _val1,_val2,_val3` code block should be used to populate the object.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: @Zack, no that doesn't look like a duplicate to this question.

Comment: Use a factory pattern.

Comment: @stumped221, why do you want such thing, you can mark your properties as *read-only* and only allow them to be set through constructors.

Comment: There is an instance where I will use the constructor.. and an instance where I will be setting the values explicitly..

Comment: I would avoid the dual default values in your second constructor. That will allow a user to set the 3rd parameter, but not the 2nd. If you want to allow that, then no worries. But the following is valid: `var x = new MyClass("v1", val_id3 = "v3");` I just wanted you to be aware of it.

Comment: You could move the logic out of the constructor and into the properties.  It might help to know what the logic is to determine the best approach.

Comment: Well.. the logic is essentially.. if I get an Ip address I lookup the dns name.. if I get a dns name I look up the ip address etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the logic that needs to be invoked in both cases to a private method, e.g.

```
class MyClass
{

    private void InitializeStuff()
    {
        //do some stuff.. set _val1,_val2,_val3
    }

    string _val1 = null;

    public string Val1
    {
        get { return _val1; } 
        set 
        {
           InitializeStuff();
           _val1 = value; // Unless InitializeStuff sets this, in which case pass value in to it.
        }
    }  

    public MyClass()
    {
        // If needed:
        InitializeStuff();
    }

    public MyClass(string val_id1, string val_id2 = null, string val_id3 = null)
    {
        InitializeStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `//do some stuff.. set _val1,_val2,_val3` in the corresponding setter.

```
class MyClass
{
    string _val1 = null;
    string _val2 = null;
    string _val3 = null;

    public string Val1
    {
        get
        {
            return _val1;
        }
        set
        {
            // do some stuff with _val1
            _val1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Val2
    {
        get
        {
            return _val2;
        }
        set
        {
            // do some stuff with _val2
            _val2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Val3
    {
        get
        {
            return _val3;
        }
        set
        {
            // do some stuff with _val3
            _val3 = value;
        }
    }

    public MyClass(){}
    public MyClass(string val_id1, string val_id2 = null, string val_id3 = null)
    {
        // Don't set _valX instead set ValX
    }
}
```